# Multiline grep regex is not working

Tags: regex, linux, apache, grep

**EDIT :** [Solved it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36796700/6219612) myself, it was a command syntax error, nothing to do with the regex.

I'm trying to match the following pattern :

```
(.*)
<FilesMatch "(^\.ht|~$|\.bak$|\.BAK$|\.old$)">
(.*)
Order Allow,Deny Deny from all
(.*)
</FilesMatch>
(.*)
<DirectoryMatch "(/CVS/|.svn)">
(.*)
Order Allow,Deny Deny from all
(.*)
</DirectoryMatch>
(.*)
```

> ```
> (.*) meaning anything
> ```

Using `grep -P "regex"` and this regex :

```
<FilesMatch \"\(\^\\\.ht\|~\$\|\\\.bak\$\|\\\.BAK\$\|\\\.old\$\)\">(.*\n){1,}Order Allow,Deny Deny from all(.*\n){1,}<\/FilesMatch>(.*\n){1,}<DirectoryMatch \"\(\/CVS\/\|\.svn\)\">(.*\n){1,}Order Allow,Deny Deny from all(.*\n){1,}<\/DirectoryMatch>
```

Over the following example file :

```
<FilesMatch "(^\.ht|~$|\.bak$|\.BAK$|\.old$)">
Order Allow,Deny Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<DirectoryMatch "(/CVS/|.svn)">
Order Allow,Deny Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

According to [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/wT1nM6/1), it is supposed to work but it doesn't, do you have any idea about what's wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey it's my own fault, I used `grep -P "regex"` instead of `grep -P 'regex'`...

It also works with `pcregrep -M 'regex'`.

Thanks anyway !

Comment: Next time, show the exact incantation that doesn't work.